# Webcam to youtube live stream with the youtube api

Tags: youtube-api, webrtc, youtube-data-api, rtmp, mpeg-dash

SO,

so, I have this web app project that I'm working on, and one of the specifications is it must allow the user to stream to a Youtube channel.

Now, it's always the same channel, so it would be ideal if I got rid of the YT auth part... but that is not why I'm here.

Anyway, the specification says that the application must allow in-browser streaming, meaning, no random gizmos, they want to be able to click a button and have the cameras connected to their device as possible inputs to this app that streams to YouTube (just like you could make them inputs to a video tag).

I have a little script that creates a stream using the live stream api, and it can provide me with ingester URLs for RTMP, DASH, and HLS.

Problem is, there seems to be no option to get the WebRTC ingester, which, obviously, must exist, because the "Go live" option exists on the website.

So, the question is: What is the path of least resistance to get from having a WebRTC stream to having that output on a youtube live stream?

The production server is php5.6 and I can use composer.

Comment: Check out my code sample here:  https://github.com/fbsamples/Canvas-Streaming-Example  While that sample uses a canvas for its source MediaStream, it can just as easily be a web cam.  And, do please note the license terms on that sample.

Comment: Do you know if this solution is supported in browsers other than chrome now?

Comment: Yeah, Chrome and Firefox work fine.  https://caniuse.com/#feat=mediarecorder

Comment: does the codec part concern me at all?